# Coap Client observe does not work for large message

Tags: javascript, iot, coap

On the client-side, I want to observe a resource with a large message and I'm getting a bad request as a status code.

I would like to intensify that for small and medium messages(size until 1K), it works well.

What do I need to do to get the payload for the large message?
Am I doing something wrong?

```js
const coap = require("coap");
const setup = {
    host: 'CLOUD_IP',
    observe: true,
    port: 5683,
    pathname: '/middlewareToCloud',
    method: 'GET'
}
const req = coap.request(setup)

// edit this to adjust max packet
req.setOption('Block2', Buffer.of(0x2))

req.on('response', (res) => 
{
    res.on('data', (data) => {           
        console.log(Buffer.from(data).toString('utf8'));
    })
    
});
req.end()
```

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you added information on which library you are using, and what sever you are working with.

Comment: Client side is [node-coap](https://github.com/mcollina/node-coap) and server-side is[libcoap](https://libcoap.net/).

I don't why I'm get bad request.

Comment: @chrysn I tried to change the size of Block2, but it did not work.

// edit this to adjust max packet
req.setOption('Block2', Buffer.of(0x6))